# Field must be secret but subclass must override the method using this field?

Tags: java

I have a design problem:

- Question class: have a question and answer (String)
- TextQuestion class: normal text question and answer
- NumberQuestion class: question (String), answer (number - int, float...), and check answer using an epsilon value

But I have a problem with NumberQuestion. I must take the right answer, convert it into number, and compare to the answer from user. So how can I get the answer? Use getter method is not secure. Or my design is not good? How can I change?

> ```
> public abstract class Question {
>   private String question;
>   private String answer;
>
>   public Question(String question, String answer) {
>       this.question = question;
>       this.answer = answer;
>   }
>
>   public boolean checkAnswer(String yourAnswer) {
>       // default implementation
>   }
> }
>
> class TextQuestion extends Question {
>   // Answer and Question is always string type, it's OK, not problem
> }
>
> class NumberQuestion extends Question {
>   // Question is String, OK
>   // Answer: input is number, accept approximately
>   // Ex: Question: 1/3 = ?
>   //     Answer: 0.3 or 0.33 or 0.333 are accepted (using an Epsilon value)
>
>   // so must override checkAnswer
>   public boolean checkAnswer(String yourAnswer) {
>       // HOW can I do?
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What do mean by "not secure"? What kind of risk are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @TedHopp: it means all classes (except its subclasses) can get the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you need to hide the answer from subclasses (or from any client code, for that matter). The client code surely needs to know the answer in the first place in order to create a `TextQuestion` or `NumberQuestion` instance.

You should abstract away the logic of the test, as well as the answer type, from the `Question` class:

```
public abstract class Question<AnswerType> {
  private String question;
  private AnswerType answer;

  public Question(String question, AnswerType answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  public abstract boolean checkAnswer(AnswerType yourAnswer);

  protected AnswerType getAnswer() {
    return answer;
  }
}

class TextQuestion extends Question<String> {
  public TextQuestion(String question, String answer) {
    super(question, answer);
  }

  public boolean checkAnswer(String yourAnswer) {
    return answer.equals(yourAnswer);
  }
}

class NumberQuestion extends Question<Double> {
  private double epsilon;

  public NumberQuestion(String question, Double answer, double epsilon) {
    super(question, answer);
    this.epsilon = epsilon;
  }

  public boolean checkAnswer(Double yourAnswer) {
    return Math.abs(getAnswer() - yourAnswer) < epsilon;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I want the Question class hide the answer from clients code, not subclasses. I wonder why protected keyword allow all classes in the same package to access this field (or method).

Answer (score 1):

If your answer can have different types you can also use generics in your abstract class.

```
public abstract class Question<T> {
    private final String question;
    protected final T answer;

    public Question(String question, T answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    //Default implementation
    public boolean checkAnswer(T yourAnswer) {
        return answer.equals(yourAnswer);
    }
}
```

And when you define subclass:

```
class NumberQuestion extends Question<BigDecimal> {
    ...
    private final BigDecimal epsilon;

    public NumericQuestion(String question, BigDecimal answer, BigDecimal epsilon) {
        super(question, answer);

        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkAnswer(BigDecimal yourAnswer) {
        BigDecimal result = this.answer.subtract(yourAnswer).abs();

        return (result.compareTo(epsilon) == -1); // check whether result < epsilon
    }
}
```

By the way, instead of double better to use BigDecimal for floating point calculations. There is a lot of good articles about this. You can "google" this question if it will be interesting for you.

If you need to set scale for floating point numbers you can easily do this with big decimal, for example:

```
result = result.setScale(5);
```

And be careful because BigDecimal class is immutable (not fully, but this is another question) and returns new instance when you try to change it's state.

Comment: OP wants to use something like `Math.abs(answer - yourAnswer) < epsilon` for numerical questions. `equals()` is generally not appropriate for floating-point comparisons.

Comment: Yes. But he can easily change default implementation in the subclass.

Comment: @dimas: but how can I check the answer in NumberQuestion? yourAnswer compare to what?

Comment: Ok. For checking answer I propose to make answer field in question class protected and final (so nobody can change it after object creation). I will adit my unswer according to this.

Comment: @dimas: OK, it's better! So no solution can make a field or method available only subclasses, not package access?

Comment: No. I can't imagine such solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with generic classes but that would be appropriate in this case. You can just google it. :-)

If you don't want to do that, you can always convert both `yourAnswer` and `this.answer` to the same type, then you can find the absolute difference and make sure they are lower than a specific threshold.

Comment: OP wants to keep `answer` secret from subclasses for some reason.